# RUN command throws "not found"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have Docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY mylib/src /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src
RUN chmod +x configure.sh
RUN ls -l # it display all files, included configure.sh
RUN ./configure.sh # error there
```

Echo:

```
RUN ls -l
 ---> Running in d9ba6b10ed2a
total 604
...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     91 Oct 28 07:30 configure.sh
...
RUN ./configure.sh
 ---> Running in 2e3e8fdca28e
/bin/sh: 1: ./configure.sh: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c ./configure.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

File configure.sh exists, but an error occurs: not found

I have this problem only on my Windows PC.

Answer (score 1):

Okaaaay... Problem was in Windows-style line separator. I change CRLF to LF in my configure.sh and it works!